# Android WEBビューでのタイトル取得がページを移動するとおかしい

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

WebViewを利用してRSSリーダーを作成しています。
getTitle() を使い、現在観覧しているページの情報を保持し、ブックマークするようにしたいのですが
getTitleがページ移動後から正常に動きません。

ソースonCreateの中

```
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    //標準ブラウザをキャンセル
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    //アプリ起動時に読み込むURL
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://lifehack2ch.livedoor.biz/");
```

ソース　ボタンリスナー

```
        String title = myWebView.getTitle();//見ているWEBビューのタイトルを取得
        Log.d(title, "title");
```

・そのページでボタンを押す　ログ
D/ライフハックちゃんねる弐式: title

・ページを移動したのちボタンを押す　ログ
I/WebView: FloatFade - run: Expired, go to STATE_NONE

WEBビューの初期ページから移動していない場合には意図通りに情報がとれています。
サイト内でクリックをし移動したのちだと、データが取れません。
なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

同様の処理で特に問題なく、移動後のタイトルが取得できています。

サンプル：

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="getTitle"
        android:text="Get Title!" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://jp.stackoverflow.com/");
}

public void getTitle(View view) {
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", webView.getTitle());
}
```

LogCat:

```
11-12 18:21:59.912 23382-23382/testapp D/LOG_TAG: スタック・オーバーフロー
11-12 18:22:10.428 23382-23382/testapp D/LOG_TAG: 新着の質問 - スタック・オーバーフロー
```

問題は（リスナーの使い方など）他の箇所にあるのではないですか？